# fill an array in imbricated for loops

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have 2 arrays of Member - one filled, the other not.
I have a list which contains all members.
I need to fill the second array with member who are not in the first array.

I tried this , but i got an outboundexception ( i am very bad with pure algorithmic :( )

```
Member[] busyMember= getBusyMember();
List<Team> allMembers= new ArrayList<Team>(jsonParsed.getAllElement());
Member[] availableMembers= new Member[allMembers.size()-busyMembers.length];


            for (int i= 0; i<allMembers.size(); i++) {
                Team t = allMembers.get(i);
                long memberId = t.getMember().getId();
                for (int j= 0 ; j<busyMember.length; j++) {
                    if (memberId != busyMember[j].getId()) {
                        availableMembers[i]=t.getMember();
                        //outboundexception here

                    }
                }

            }
```

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Why arrays? Use sets and lists and you won't have these issues... Every second collections question seems to be on operating with arrays where standard collections would turn the problem into a trivial one. Sigh.... The way you ask your question cries for "do not use arrays"

Comment: @OlegS. I know it s much easier to treat with Collections instead arrays but in my case it's an instruction who i must respect :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just use `Lists` and the [`removeAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method. If you really need an array, you can always call the method [`toArray(T[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) on the resulting list.

```
List<Member> busyMember= Arrays.asList(getBusyMember());
List<Team> allMembers= new ArrayList<Team>(jsonParsed.getAllElement());
List<Member> availableMembers = new ArrayList<Member>();
for(Team t : allMembers){
    availableMembers.add(t.getMember());
}
availableMembers.removeAll(busyMember);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately I have to work with arrays because it is the instruction that was given to me.  But i will opt for your solution and call toArray méthod

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `allMembers` has more elements than `busyMember`, you just need to change the statement

```
for (int i= 0; i<allMembers.size(); i++)
```

to

```
for (int i= 0; i<availableMembers.size(); i++)
```

There are other changes that you would need to do for consistency, but this is another discussion :-)

Comment: While this will resolve the current exception, this will result in another logical issue.

Comment: @PNS Thank you for your help . Indeed , this resolve my problem , but it doesn't read all datas of allMembers array( because it's limited to availableMembers.size())

Comment: Which means you need to do the revision, as per ZouZou's suggestion, or manually keep track of the correct index values.